# Deflater: is it possible to clone state (or rollback)?

Tags: java, deflate

Suppose I'm using a [Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) to compress a stream of bytes, and at some intervals I have the option of feeding it with two different byte arrays (two alternative representations of the same info), so that I can choose the most compressible one. Ideally, I would like to be able to clone the state of a "live" deflater, so that I can feed each instance with an array, check the results, and discard the undesirable one.
Alternatively, I'd like to mark the current state (sort of a savepoint) so that, after feeding and compressing  with `setInput()` + `deflate()` I can rollback/reset to that state to try with different data.

Looking at the API, this seems to me rather impossible... nor even reimplementing the `Deflater` (not at least if one wants to take advantage of the internal native implementation). Am I right? Any ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that the Java interface to [zlib](http://zlib.net/manual.html) provides zlib's `deflateCopy()` operation.  It is possible that the inherited clone operation is properly implemented and does a `deflateCopy()`, but I don't know.